# Execute concurrent async functions on each element of the hashmap using rayon::par_iter with for_each

Tags: rust

Can I do something like this ?

I want to execute concurrent async functions on each element of the hashmap.

```
async fn b(){
 let hm: HashMap<String,String> = ...;
   
 hm.par_iter().for_each(async move |(k, v)| {
    ...operations on k,v

      another_func(&v).await;
 })
}
```

**Error on async move:**

*`async move {`rustcE0658
mismatched types

expected unit type `()`
found opaque type `impl std::future::Future`rustcE0308
mod.rs(61, 43): the found opaque type*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rayon` is not a good fit for async because it operates on ordinary non-async functions, and blocks in operations like `for_each()`. But since you're using async, you could avoid Rayon altogether and just spawn a task for each operation:

```
let tasks: Vec<_> = hm
    .iter()
    .map(|(k, v)| {
        let k = k.clone();
        let v = v.clone();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            some_func(&k, &v);
            another_func(&v).await;
        })
    })
    .collect();
future::join_all(tasks).await;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e769f641f6122e54b9c00e8339d2f084)

Note that we clone the keys and the values because that allows them to be safely moved into the task. Without the clone the borrow checker cannot prove that a reference to the data in the hash table passed to a global task won't outlive the hash table itself.